# No static resource swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to access swagger UI. But I am getting below error. I don't mention any default static path in application.properties.

// gradle dependencies

```
 springdoc.openapi.ui)
```

**URL:**
http://localhost:7666/al/swagger-ui.html

**Error:**

```
 {
    "message": "No static resource swagger-ui.html.",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": "2023-12-08T18:50:22.998920556"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded 'org.springframework.boot' to version '2.7.5' from '3.2.2' and the error was gone.